# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 что то в jsonparser

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь переделать под себя проект [как работать с mysql в android](http://devcolibri.com/1548). Все переписал под себя, но выходить данная ошибка

```
06-03 13:03:49.880 10844-10884/com.example.andrey.projectudsu 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.example.andrey.projectudsu, PID: 10844
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
        at parser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:53)
        at com.example.andrey.projectudsu.RatingActivity$LoadAllAbiturients.doInBackground(RatingActivity.java:98)
        at com.example.andrey.projectudsu.RatingActivity$LoadAllAbiturients.doInBackground(RatingActivity.java:75)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

mainactivity

```
package com.example.andrey.projectudsu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button ratingBtn;
Button addAbiturBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ratingBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ratingBtn);
    addAbiturBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAbiturBtn);
}

public void rating(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RatingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void addAbitur(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAbiturActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

addabituractivity

```
package com.example.andrey.projectudsu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.andrey.projectudsu.R;

import parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.message.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AddAbiturActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText ETlastname;
EditText ETfirstname;
EditText ETpatronymic;
EditText ETege_points;

String lastname = ETlastname.getText().toString();
String firstname = ETfirstname.getText().toString();
String patronymic = ETpatronymic.getText().toString();
String ege_points = ETege_points.getText().toString();

private static String url_add_abiturient = "http://192.168.43.224/add_abiturient.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_abitur);

    ETlastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    ETfirstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    ETpatronymic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.patronymic);
    ETege_points = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ege_points);

    Button addIntoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addIntoBDBtn);

    addIntoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new addNewAbiturient().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Фоновый Async Task создания нового продукта
 **/
class addNewAbiturient extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед согданием в фоновом потоке показываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddAbiturActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage ("Добавление абитуриента...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Добавление абитуриента
     **/
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {


        // Заполняем параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patronymic", patronymic));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ege_points", ege_points));

        // получаем JSON объект
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_abiturient, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // абитуриент успешно добавлен создан
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RatingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // закрываем это окно
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После оконачния скрываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

ratingactivity

```
package com.example.andrey.projectudsu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RatingActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Создаем JSON парсер
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> abiturientsList;

// url получения списка всех продуктов
private static String url_all_abiturients = "http://192.168.43.224/get_all_abiturients.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ABITURIENTS = "abiturients";
private static final String TAG_ID_ABITURIENT = "abiturient";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastname";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
private static final String TAG_EGE_POINTS = "ege_points";

// тут будет хранится список продуктов
JSONArray abiturients = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);

    // Hashmap for ListView
   abiturientsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Загружаем список в фоновом потоке
    new LoadAllAbiturients().execute();

    // получаем ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();



}




/**
 * Фоновый Async Task для загрузки всех продуктов по HTTP запросу
 * */
class LoadAllAbiturients extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом фонового потока Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    /*@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RatingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка списка. Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }*/

    /**
     * Получаем список абитуриентов из url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Будет хранить параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // получаем JSON строк с URL
        JSONObject json = jParser. makeHttpRequest(url_all_abiturients, "GET",params);

        Log.d("All abiturients: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // абитуриент найден
                // Получаем масив из Абитуриентов
                abiturients = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ABITURIENTS);

                // перебор всех продуктов
                for (int i = 0; i < abiturients.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = abiturients.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                    String id_abiturient = c.getString(TAG_ID_ABITURIENT);
                    String lastname = c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String firstname = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String ege_points = c.getString(TAG_EGE_POINTS);

                    // Создаем новый HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                    map.put(TAG_ID_ABITURIENT, id_abiturient);
                    map.put(TAG_LASTNAME, lastname);
                    map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
                    map.put(TAG_EGE_POINTS, ege_points);

                    // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                    abiturientsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // абитуриент не найден
                // Запускаем AddAbiturActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddAbiturActivity.class);
                // Закрытие всех предыдущие activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог после получение все продуктов

        //pDialog.dismiss();
        // обновляем UI форму в фоновом потоке
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        RatingActivity.this, abiturientsList,
                        R.layout.activity_rating, new String[] { TAG_ID_ABITURIENT,
                        TAG_LASTNAME, TAG_FIRSTNAME, TAG_EGE_POINTS},
                        new int[] { R.id.id_abiturient, R.id.lname, R.id.fname, R.id.ege});
                // обновляем listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

jsonparser

```
package parser;

import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// метод получение json объекта по url
// используя HTTP запрос и методы POST или GET
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Создаем HTTP запрос
    try {

        // проверяем метод HTTP запроса
        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // пытаемся распарсить строку в JSON объект
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // возвращаем JSON строку
    return jObj;

}

}
```

Ошибка возникает после запуска обоих `intent`.

Comment: ругается после запуска обоих intent

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultHttpClient` устарел с API 22 и полностью удалён с API 23.

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption.

Используйте `HttpURLConnection`.